# Why the image from design view cannot be seen on device?

Tags: android, imageview

I've put an image view on the first activity, I can see it both in design and on my  actual device.
When I change the image with another one, it changes in design view too but doesn't appear anymore on my device, although the constraints remain the same.

Any idea why?

LE: the size of the second picture was significantly bigger, so I guess that's the reason. I resized it and now it shows up on device too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it happens due to resolutions of images. you can use this https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example to generate all resolution u want or u can add nine-patches plugin to android studio directly.

This https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch will help to add that plugin to android studio

**There is another library call glide**. https://github.com/bumptech/glide you can use this also to render the image. **I think this will simply solve your problem** without creating images for all resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the problem with changes what you do in an XML file that does not build with APK and new changes do not visible while running every time.
Please try this option: 
Goto Run -> Edit configurations -> Miscellaneous -> disable the checkbox "Skip installation if APK has not changed" and try this, please.